# HV000030: No validator could be found for constraint 'javax.validation.constraints.Pattern' validating type 'java.util.Date'

Tags: java, spring, validation, constraints, lombok

So I made a class that checks up the RequestBody I send through a POST method, and I can't stop getting this error :

> HV000030: No validator could be found for constraint
> 'javax.validation.constraints.Pattern' validating type
> 'java.util.Date'. Check configuration for 'dateTo'

Class Command:

```
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import javax.validation.constraints.NotEmpty;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Pattern;
import java.util.Date;
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Command {

    @Pattern(regexp = "^\\d{4}\\-(0?[1-9]|1[012])\\-(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$",message = "INVALID_DATE_FORMAT")
    @NotEmpty(message = "REQUIRED_INPUT")
    private Date dateFrom;

    @Pattern(regexp = "^\\d{4}\\-(0?[1-9]|1[012])\\-(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$",message = "INVALID_DATE_FORMAT")
    @NotEmpty(message = "REQUIRED_INPUT")
    private Date dateTo;
}
```

Post Method :

```
@PostMapping(value = "/room/{id}/roomPrices",  headers = {
        "content-type=application/json" }, consumes = "application/json")
@Operation(tags = "Check room")
public testResponse postTest(@Valid @RequestBody Command command,
                             @PathVariable String id) {
    Command resp = this.roomService.getTest(id,command);
    return new testResponse (resp, HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```

I'm not posting postTest function's code simply because it doesnt even get reached before the error shows up, due to the @Valid annotation, if the constraint is not valid the application doesnt go any further.

While I've tried to change the pattern to ".*" just to make sure that the annotation is working, still same error shows up. it only get skipped when I remove the @Pattern annotation.

Now I have no clue how to troubleshoot this issue. is there a conflict between the Date data type and Pattern ? it seems to be working fine when the data type is String for another command class.

Comment: [The documentation](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/validation/constraints/Pattern.html) is clear:  “Accepts CharSequence. null elements are considered valid.”  You may only use `@Pattern` on properties whose type is CharSequence or something that implements CharSequence (like String).  Date does not implement CharSequence.  Date objects do not have a character pattern at all;  they are just wrappers for the number of milliseconds since the start of January 1 1970.

Comment: thank you! did not pay attention to that.